# Is SBOL-VOWS operational?

Tags: visualization, sbol, ontology

[Synthetic Biology Open Language's Visual Ontology Webservice](https://vows.sbolstandard.org/) docs have example URLs but they all return a github pages 404.

EDIT:
The SBOL-VOWS has site has been fixed but the [section on the SBOL website](https://sbolstandard.org/sbol-visual-ontology/) still has links with a 404.

Comment: would you mind adding the link in the docs that returns 404 github page? And perhaps mentioning what did you expect to see there instead? It just so people will be more easily understand/find your question if then have the same problem.

Comment: @KamilSJaron ah my bad. I just realized that SBOL website itself still has broken links!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many thanks for raising this issue. The web service is now working. Only the glyph related web service calls were affected due to restructuring folders at the SBOL-Visual GitHub repository. I now revived the glyphs using the sbol-visual-ontology GitHub repository. Over the summer, we will develop the web service further so that you can request different versions of glyphs. Currently, the web service works with the SBOL Visual v2.3 glyphs and we will provide support for SBOL Visual v3 glyphs soon.

The web service is available at:
https://vows.sbolstandard.org/

Please let me know if there is anything I can clarify.

Comment: Hello - I've just noticed the links on the [SBOL website](https://sbolstandard.org/sbol-visual-ontology/) are still broken.